# Migration tool is too much on the Internet. Which one is good at migrationg from VirtueMart to Magento?

Tags: migration

I'm hesitating in choosing migration tools , I want to migrate from VirtueMart to Magento. My old website with 90000 entities and I want to keep the customers passwords after converting. Please advise me.

Comment: Several migration questions we're posted in the last couple of days. Please check the answers provided for those questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Cart2Cart](http://www.shopping-cart-migration.com/) seems to be the most used tool to move things around. They have a plan to move entities around VirtueMart to Magento [here](http://www.shopping-cart-migration.com/shopping-cart-migration-options/158-virtuemart-to-magento-migration).